# How to read single item details with multiple rows from uneven data in excel using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel something like this -

[image]

and I want an output like this -

[image]

Basically, I need to convert headers as line items and only the headers with non-zero amount should be picked for an employee. Example: Overtime Earnings will be added for only Employee 2 as it has non-zero amount. Also, for "Other Type", the description to be considered are the column values except 'Total' and the corresponding amount should be picked from "Other Earnings".

Is there any way to achieve this using pandas library?

Thanks in advance.